# What is the best way to handle ERC20 token payments internally in the another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, tokens, erc-20

I'm trying to handle ERC20 token payments, using the instance of the deployed ERC20 smart contract in another smart contract, but getting the following error:

[image]

> contract SimpleSmartContract

```
function mintTo(address account, address tokenAddr) public {
        CustomERC20 ERC20Token = CustomERC20(tokenAddr);
        require(address(tokenAddr) != address(0), "Minting unexisting ERC20 token is not possible");
        ERC20Token.mint(account, 1);
    }

    function transferTo(address spender, address recipient, address tokenAddr) public {
        CustomERC20 ERC20Token = CustomERC20(tokenAddr);

        ERC20Token.transferFromERC20(spender, recipient, 1);
    }
```

> contract CustomERC20 is ERC20

```
function transferFromERC20(
        address spender,
        address recepient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external {
        emit payment(spender, recepient);
        _approve(spender, recepient, amount);
        transferFrom(spender, recepient, amount);
    }

    function mint(address recepient, uint256 amount) external {
        _mint(recepient, amount);
    }
```

How I would fix this error? What are another ways to handle payments like this?

Comment: You cant approve and transfer on the same transaction, you must call and wait for approve to be mined and then call the transfer function.

Comment: The comment is not correct. With the default erc20 implementation from openzepplin you can approve and transfer in the same tx.